# $y=ce^{y/x};\quad y'=y^2/(xy-x^2)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem says that the left function is an implicit solution of that differential equation and I have to prove it.

My try: $$y'=-ce^{y/x}\cdot\frac{y'x-y}{x^2}=\frac{y}{x^2}\cdot(y'x-y)=-\frac{y^2}{x^2}+\frac{yy'}{x}\Rightarrow y'=\frac{y^2}{x^2}\frac{y-x}{x}\Rightarrow y'=?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$y'=D_{x}[ce^{y/x}]=ce^{y/x}\cdot D_{x}[y/x]=y(-y/x^{2}+y'/x)=\frac{y}{x^{2}}(xy'-y)$$

as you computed.  Re-arranging we have

$$y'-\frac{xyy'}{x^{2}}=-\frac{y^{2}}{x^{2}}.$$

Therefore

$$y'(1-\frac{xy}{x^{2}})=y'(\frac{x^{2}-xy}{x^{2}})=-\frac{y^{2}}{x^{2}},$$
or
$$y'(x^{2}-xy)=-y^{2},$$
or
$$y'=\frac{y^{2}}{xy-x^{2}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

we have $y=ce^{y/x}$ and $y=y(x)$ by differentiating with respect to $x$ we get
$$x^2y'=ce^{y/x}(y'x-y)$$
$$y'(x^2-xce^{y/x})=-yce^{y/x}$$
plugging $y=ce^{y/x}$ in or equation we obtain
$$y'(x^2-xy)=-y^2$$ or 
$$y'=\frac{y^2}{xy-x^2}$$ if $xy-x^2\neq 0$